# github_repos: Join "commits" and "content" table

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to retrieve the file content of a file at a given commit in Googles BigQuery Github Dataset ("github_repos").

Hence I would expect something like `SELECT content FROM sample_contents WHERE commit_id = abc` (just as one example. In the future it should be a join). But sadly I am not able to find a link i.e. an attribute which is shared between the `commits`-table and the `contents`-table.

How can I join the tables `commits` and `contents`?

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the table file to join these two tables `commits` and `contents`.

You can see this example:

```
with example as (
  SELECT a.id as idFiles,b.id as idContents,a.repo_name as idContents_1,c.repo_name as idCommit_1
  FROM `files`  a
  join `contents` b on a.id=b.id
  join `commits` c on a.repo_name=ARRAY_TO_STRING(c.repo_name, "")
  where a.repo_name='conda-forge/feedstocks' and a.id='c798dafa5d536d96203f762db8fd11cbde8f3139'
)
select *
from example limit 10
```

As you can see in this image, the table `files` uses the field `id` to join the table `contents` because it uses the same `id` field. The table `files` uses the field `repo_name` to join the table `commit`. You must use the table `files` to join the tables `commit` and `contents`. You can’t join these two tables directly (commit and contents).

[image]

Comment: As I would join the two tables by their repositories name, your query would return all the files in the repository regardless of the commit?

I think it is not possible because the `files` and `contents` tables do not store any history.

Comment: @Felixm I update my answer.